# How do I convert an array of Promises to a stream (of Observables?)

Tags: promise, rxjs

Let's say I have an array of promises, `itemsPromises`. Some of them will fail, half of them will probably succeed.

If I try to get the responses like so:

```
const itemsPromises = raw.map(item =>
            axios({
                method:'get',
                url:`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apikey}&i=${item.imdbID}`
            })
        )
```

`const itemsResponses = await Promise.all(itemsPromises)`

...I will need to wait a LONG time until the failing promises time out, eventually. I may get 5-6 successful reponses but won't have access to them untill ALL of the promises are resolved or rejected.

Can I convert this array of Promises to some iterable form of Observables, so that every time I get a successful response I can pass it on to my application and use it?

Comment: What do you want to do with rejected promises? How should they be represented in the stream? Are the only errors you're expecting timeout errors?

Comment: I don't mind losing them. I don't know how their API works - sometimes I get errors complaining I'm not using the 'correct' headers, most of the time I don't get any errors at all, just never-resolving-or-rejecting Promises. Usually at least half of my requests get resolved in time with proper data (I can see that using Chrome dev tools), the other get stuck in limbo but I don't mind what happens to them after 2-3 seconds, as long as I get the few successful responses back at least.

Answer (score 3):

Merge operator lets you execute each http call simultaneously

```
Rx.Observable.merge(null,
raw.map(item =>
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=b54e8554&i=${item.imdbID}`
    })).catch(err=>Rx.Observable.of({err,item}))
)).subscribe()
```

Comment: You can leave out the `this`, as `Rx.Observable.merge` is static and does not use a context. You could just pass `null` or `undefined`. Also, `Rx.Observable.merge` should accept a single, array argument. Or you could use the array spread syntax.

Comment: I'll edit it. I tried the array as argument, but it's not working though.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. There is no overload that takes an array argument, so the array-spread syntax would be the only other option.

Comment: You might want to tweak your answer to swallow (or log) per-promise errors - as outlined in the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056097/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-promises-to-a-stream-of-observables#comment83086570_48056097).

Comment: Also pretty sure you don't need `fromPromise` and that merge will do `from` for you.